# What are some common causes for the "package does not exist" error in Java unit tests when building with Maven that can be caused by renaming classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, junit, surefire

I have a situation where I'm renaming 3 classes in the same directory/package in Java. After renaming, everything is building fine using Maven 3 in src/main.

However, my junit tests in src/test are now complaining that none of the packages exist after I renamed the classes there as well.

I did not make any changes to the directory structure and I triple-checked that the package name in the Java files are fine and the directory structure is fine as well. Interestingly, I'm also getting this error for subdirectories of the location where I changed the class names in src/main.

Although I cannot copy/paste the code directly, the following is a quick example of what I have changed:

For the renamed files, I did something along the lines of:

```
com.companyxyz.packageabc.MyCurrentClass
```

to:

```
com.companyxyz.packageabc.MyNewClass
```

Again, I updated unit test code and application code to use the new class name; no change was made in the directory structure of the unit tests, although I did rename the unit test to align with the new class name as well. However, as mentioned above, the unit tests are now complaining:

```
[ERROR] /myrepopath/src/test/java/com/companyxyz/packageabc/junit/MyNewClassTest.java:[3,33] package com.companyxyz.packageabc does not exist
```

As mentioned above, I triple-checked the directory structure did not change and everything looks good with the package name in the java file showing:

```
package com.companyxyz.packageabc
```

Additionally, I am doing a Maven install before running:

```
mvn clean install -U && mvn clean package
```

If I revert the changes back to before I made the class name change, everything builds just fine without a problem.

Is this enough information for somebody to point me in the correct direction to find out what is going on with this error?

Or does anyone know of any common pitfalls that might occur when renaming a class in Java that could produce this type of issue in the unit tests?

Any help would be appreciated. I have a lot of C++ experience, but less on Java and have not run into this situation before. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: For some additional context, I backed out all of the changes and tried again one file at a time rebuilding at checkpoints rather than trying to rename all at once. This time I had no issues and everything builds fine. I would still appreciate if anyone was able to add an answer as to what could have possibly gone wrong in the terms of a potential error in renaming one of the classes and why Java would complain about the package rather than not finding a symbol when no directories/packages were changed. Seems very poor error messaging, but not experienced enough in Java to know for certain.

Comment: Hmm. without getting a copy of your project this might be difficult to reproduce. How are you doing the renaming, are you doing it manually or using the IDE to rename classes? If the former, you have have missed a rename somewhere. Are you able to create a gist of your project? (obviously with code removed)

Comment: Well based on the information provided this should work - the most common issue i can imagine here is that something in the dependencies has changed (like excludes?) or that the reactor build order is messed up for reasons (is the module containing the MyCurrentClass/MyClass the same Maven module as the one containing the tests complaining?). Your tests are however not located under `src/main/java/` which is a common reason for the exception as well. I suggest you add plugin definitions of say the surfire plugin for further support (this will normaly not contain any sensitive data)

Comment: Additional questions to check in your setup regarding changed dependencies: Are you using "*-SNAPSHOT"-Versions? Could it be that you refactored under a new version but your test-project contains dependency information to a older version? (assumed its not the unit-tests of the same module)

Comment: @Jimmy I think your comment might help get to the root of this and something along the lines of what I was suspecting. I was renaming manually and it is possible that I missed a rename somewhere. However, if I did miss a rename, why would I get a package does not exist error instead of an error that the symbol could not be found? If this can be answered, it is enough for me to accept the answer since I was able to rename without an issue when I was "more careful" about it. Again, I'm still at a lost as to why a bad rename would cause the package does not exist instead of a bad symbol error.